# Stata Matrix Creation Assign value

Tags: matrix, stata

1. To create a matrix M= (N*50)
   matrix m=J(N,50,.)

   Since I want to change the number of observation overtime, how to I set N=number of observations?
2. How to specific each element of the matrix, e.g. M(1,2) (element in row1, column2)?
3. How to I assign value to each element of the matrix? For example I want to set O to the first row to be all 0, i.e. M(1,1)=M(1,2)=...M(1,50)=0?

Answer (score 1):

```
. // an (empty) dataset with 5 observations
. clear all

. set obs 5
obs was 0, now 5

. 
. // go to Mata
. mata:
------------------------------------------------- mata (type end to exit) -------------------------
: 
: // collect the number of observations
: n = st_nobs()

: 
: // create matrix M (n x 10)
: M = J(n, 10, .)

: 
: // see it:
: M
        1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10
    +---------------------------------------------------+
  1 |   .    .    .    .    .    .    .    .    .    .  |
  2 |   .    .    .    .    .    .    .    .    .    .  |
  3 |   .    .    .    .    .    .    .    .    .    .  |
  4 |   .    .    .    .    .    .    .    .    .    .  |
  5 |   .    .    .    .    .    .    .    .    .    .  |
    +---------------------------------------------------+

: 
: // fill the first row with 0s
: M[1,.] = J(1,10,0)

: 
: // See cell 1,2
: M[1,2]
  0

: 
: // see cell 2,3
: M[2,3]
  .

: end
```

Comment: Genius! Many Thanks!
I find Stata unforgiving, e.g. If I make typo, I can't undo. I must clear and restart everything. Any solution?
For instance,   
set obs 5
mata:
n = st_nobs()
M = J(n, 10, .)
M[1,.] = J(1,9,0)
r(3200)
M = J(n, 10, .)
r199

meaning I have to clear and restart....

Comment: I don't see how that forces you to restart. Such errors will kick you out of Mata into Stata, but you can just start Mata again, and the elements you created will still be there. However, it is good practice to always work with .do files. That way you can fix the .do file and rerun it in its entirity so you do not have to rely on stuff that were left behind after a buggy run. This leads to much more stable code.

Comment: Come to think of it, that is exactly what I did. I wrote the example in a .do file, made some errors (I tried to display `m` instead of `M`), when I tried to run it I saw that Stata complained, I fixed the .do file and ran it again. It was not necessary, I could have opened Mata and typed `M` to see the matrix and continue building the example from there. By changing the .do file instead I made sure that if you ran the example there was not an undetected bug left behind.

Comment: Make sense! Thanks again. :) I have searched through User's Guide. But still have some doubts. 
1. How to create and save .do file? I can only save a .dta file only when I have created a variable. 
2. What if i want to generate a number ~N(a,b) in entire row or particular element of a matrix? There is no such thing as
M[1,.] = M(1,10,rnormal(a,b))

Comment: Did you type `search do` in Stata?

Answer (score 0):

Creating a .do file.

Just use any text editor, including Stata's do-file editor, and save with the extension `.do`.

The same random normal deviate in a row. Here is one way:

```
: m = J(5,5, .)

: m[1,] = J(1, 5, rnormal(1,1,0,1))

: m
                 1             2             3             4             5
    +-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
  1 |  2.285713101   2.285713101   2.285713101   2.285713101   2.285713101  |
  2 |            .             .             .             .             .  |
  3 |            .             .             .             .             .  |
  4 |            .             .             .             .             .  |
  5 |            .             .             .             .             .  |
    +-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks Cox. Follow up. 1. rnormal(a,b,mean,sd)?
what are a and b respectively?
2. Can any one of these 4 elements inside rnormal be a scalar or variable? 
3. How about different number in same row? E.g. use foreach loop to generate different number in the same row possible?

Comment: If you're Joey, I'm Nick. That friendly gesture aside, sorry, but you're asking too many questions for me. There's a limit to everyone's time and altruism. You just have to get into the habit of reading the help and experimenting.

Comment: I am sorry Nick. Grateful for your prompt replies and thanks for the advice.:)

Comment: type in Stata `help mata rnormal()`